# Intermittent A/C Nissan Note 2006

Tags: ac, nissan

The A/C in my car works great, but after running it for 15 mins or so, the temperature rapidly increases, to the point where the A/C breeze is only slighly colder than the temperature in the car. After roughly 10 mins, the A/C is cold again.

I've observed the engine bay when the A/C gets warm and I haven't noticed any freezing of the line nor compressor.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Any possible ideas on the source of the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Is it the dCi or the 1.4 petrol variant?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is the compressor still engaged when it stops blowing cold?

Comment: @milison I will verify and get back  to you

Comment: @al_ its a petrol vehicle definitely, but i will confirm for sure

Comment: The diesel one has a variable displacement internal control Sanden SD6V12 piston compressor. The petrol one a Valeo DKV type vane compressor. These two compressors operate very differently: for example the first one is supposed to remain in working state (clutch engaged) as long as AC is requested. The other one is instead supposed to cycle and doesn't seem to come with a thermal protection switch in series with the clutch unlike other vane/scroll compressors.

Comment: @milison the compressor is not engaged when the A/C gets warm

Comment: @Al_ the engine model is a HR15

Comment: Valeo DKV08R then. Unfortunately, i can't help you. It can be a clutch assembly/coil issue, a wiring one or a relay one.

Comment: If it is the clutch, next time it quits, find something to tap the front with, and if it engages, then there may be excessive clutch gap.  If not, then pressure gauges need to be connected next to see if anything is getting out of range

Comment: @milison i will try that the next time and see if thats the cause of the issue

Comment: @milison, i hit it while it was running and the saw the clutch engaged, the alternator started spinning

Comment: Do you mean the compressor?

Comment: @milison, my apologies, i meant to say compressor.

Comment: So it needs a clutch, or shim removed from the clutch plate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following issues were the source of the problem:

- The coil had worn out and as such was not able to produce enough
  magnetic force to engage the pulley and turn on the compressor. This was fixed by replacing the coil completely
- There was corrosion next to the coil which prevented it from properly being grounded and thereby not allowing engagement of the clutch. This was resolved by simply sanding the area next to the coil to allow for proper grounding

Comment: I also suggest you to have the system regassed (so that the system is running with optimal charge) and replace the AC clutch relay (they eventually wear out) to give it a finishing touch. Also, remember to turn on the compressor for at least some minutes every week. Helps keeping the charge inside for a longer time.